# Cannot get routeData in IExceptionHandler.TryHandleAsync() for ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

### Major Issues

**For trying the new feature IExceptionHandler of ASP.NET Core 8 based on the article: [(Milan Jovanovic) Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Core 8](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/global-error-handling-in-aspnetcore-8).**
**I have the following code, and the context.GetRouteData() always return null.**
**Is it the bug of IExceptionHandler and app.UseExceptionHandler(); ?**

### Sample Repository in GitHub

[IssuesRepository](https://github.com/jasper-lai/ExceptionHandler01)

### Description

I want to log the controller name and action name when exception occurs.

I’ve found the Program.cs call UseExceptionHandler() twice:
(1) `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");`
(2) `app.UseExceptionHandler();`

But even comment the first app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error"); , still cannot get the routeData.

I've tried the custom middleware (ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs) to catch exception, it can get the routeData.

the related code as follows:

**GlobalExceptionHandler.cs**

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> _logger;

    public GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
        HttpContext context, 
        Exception exception, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // !!! the routeData is always null  !!!
        var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
        var controllerName = routeData?.Values["controller"]?.ToString();
        var actionName = routeData?.Values["action"]?.ToString();

        _logger.LogInformation("Controller={controller} Action={action}", controllerName, actionName);

        var response = new ProblemDetails()
        {
            Status = 500,
            Title = "Internal Server Error",
            Detail = "occurs Internal Server Error, please contact MIS",
            Instance = context.Request.Path,
        };

        // 
        await context.Response
            .WriteAsJsonAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using ExceptionHandler01.Middlewares;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

#region (jasper) register GlobalExceptionHandler and ProblemDeatils to DI
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

//// (jasper) use custom exception handler
//app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

// (jasper) use default exception handler
app.UseExceptionHandler();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

### Refreence

- [(Milan Jovanovic) Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Core 8](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/global-error-handling-in-aspnetcore-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

After debug the source code, I found we can't get route data in `IExceptionHandler`.  It's by design.

We can find `line 143` in `ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.cs` file, in [github is line 164](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b9eaae011790c0afd86948ac3e9641a1fbd847b5/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.cs#L164). In `ClearHttpContext` method, it set the `RouteValues` to null. This is the root cause for this issue.

[image]

[image]

If you are interesting in debug source code, [you can check the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/debug-aspnetcore-source?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

**How I debug it**

Create a custom middleware and watch the context value.

[image]

---

You can try using the code below to get routing information from that location even if an exception occurs.

```
...
var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
    {
        appError.Run(async context =>
        {
            var routeData = context.Features.Get<IRoutingFeature>()?.RouteData;
            if (routeData != null)
            {
                context.Items["controller"] = routeData.Values["controller"];
                context.Items["action"] = routeData.Values["action"];
            }
            // handling the exception
        });
    });
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

...

app.UseRouting();

// capture route data
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    // You can save route data in HttpContext.Items here
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code, and I've tried on the [GitHub](https://github.com/jasper-lai/ExceptionHandler01/tree/branch_test01) **branch_test01**. 

I've implemented your code and successfully set the controller/action within another middleware. However, I encountered an issue where the expression `var routeData = context.Features.Get<IRoutingFeature>()?.RouteData;` consistently returns null.

My primary goal is to explore the use of IExceptionHandler. Would you be able to offer any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue?

Comment: Hi @jasper I have found the root cause, it's by design, please kindly check it. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi, @Jason Pan, Thank you for your help, and for providing the entire tracking process, which has benefited me greatly.